# InvalidOperation while doing a post method in PS

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I'm trying to create a comment in a Azure Devops Pull Request thread:

```
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12

# Variables
$organization = "movieseat"
$project = "pokedex"
$repositoryId = "Pokedex"
$pullRequestId = "97"
$threadId = "283" 

$pat = "Bearer $env:System_AccessToken"

$body = @"
{
    "content"="Finished building feature branch"
    "commentType"="text";
}
"@ 

$postURL = "https://dev.azure.com/$organization/$project/_apis/git/repositories/$repositoryId/pullRequests/$pullRequestId/threads/$threadId/comments?api-version=5.0"
$prComment = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $postURL -Headers @{Authorization = $pat} -Body $body -Method Post -ContentType 'application/json'

Write-Output $prComment
```

But during the release step I get:

```
Invoke-RestMethod : {"$id":"1","innerException":null,"message":"Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: 
comment","typeName":"System.ArgumentNullException, 
mscorlib","typeKey":"ArgumentNullException","errorCode":0,"eventId":0}
At D:\a\r1\a\_Pokedex master\PokeDexArtifact\release\commentURL.ps1:49 char:14
+ ... prComment = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $postURL -Headers @{Authorization  ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~     + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-RestMethod], WebException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeRestMethodCommand
##[error]PowerShell exited with code '1'.
##[section]Finishing: PowerShell Script
```

I can't find any info relating to this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure, but I think this was the actual error:

> message":"Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: comment",

```
$body = @"
    {
        "content": "http://google.com",
        "commentType": "text";
    }
"@
```

Running the code like this works. Notice the `,` after the content value. Although I removed the `commentType` value since it works without it as well.

// edit. I've updated the code block, replaced a `=` with a `:` in the content line.

Comment: the above would probably fail as well (as your initial attempt) because both of these are not valid json, valud json wouldn't have `=` and `;`. it would be a valid json with the `commentType` though. that would explain why it works now

Comment: I can confirm that this line: `"content": "$featureReleaseUrl"` works :). `=` is indeed not correct.

Answer (score 0):

```
{
    "content"="Finished building feature branch"
    "commentType"="text";
}
```

That is not valid JSON. The best way to handle creating JSON strings in PowerShell is to use `ConvertTo-Json` on an associative array:

```
$body = @{
 content = 'Finished building feature branch'
 commentType = 'text'
} | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 10
```